# How to Build a Xamarin Library Component from existing .net library

Tags: c#, android, .net, dll, xamarin

I'm trying to build a xamarine library component like "Facebook SDK". I've already built the .net library. Now I want to upload that library as component on xamarin.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. I've a XYZ.dll file which was written in .NET framework 4.0. Now I want to use that dll file to make a xamarine component. I'm following the instructions from here components.xamarin.com/guidelines

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812870/build-a-xamarin-component-using-and-existing-dll-file

Answer (score 1):

The original code base does only cover Microsoft platforms.

If your goal is to compile the code base against Xamarin profiles (iOS and Android), you need to create new projects using Xamarin specific project templates in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio, and then add the source files in, and compile and fix issues.

Alternatively, you can create a portable class library project with Xamarin profiles chosen.

Only when you have the binaries compiled against Xamarin profiles, you can pack them up following Xamarin's guidelines. Otherwise, your submission is not qualified.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is a bit confusing so I'm assuming you're looking to reference other projects from your Xamarin project.

This outlines how to do that:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_3_-_setting_up_a_xamarin_cross_platform_solution/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me rephrase my question. I've a XYZ.dll file which was written in .NET framework 4.0. Now I want to use that dll file to make a xamarine component. I'm following the instructions from here https://components.xamarin.com/guidelines