# Build a Xamarin Component Using and existing .DLL file

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono, xamarin

I already have a .dll file which was developed using .NET framework 4.0. I want to use this dll file to build a Xamarin Component.

I'm following the guide https://components.xamarin.com/guidelines but nothing working my way. Always get following error:

> Blockquote
>       Unhandled Exception:
>       Xamarin.Components.Packaging.InvalidPackageException: Could not find lib directo
>       ry, no binaries included in component package.
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.ComponentPackage.PopulateAvailableFrameworks (
>       ) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.ComponentPackage.Init () [0x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.ComponentPackage..ctor (System.String file) [0
>       x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.Creation.PackageCreator.ValidatePackage (Syste
>       m.String packagePath) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.CreateManuallyCommandHandler.Invoke (System.String[] arg
>       s) [0x00000] in :0
>       [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Xamarin.Components.Packaging.InvalidPackageEx
>       ception: Could not find lib directory, no binaries included in component package
>       .
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.ComponentPackage.PopulateAvailableFrameworks (
>       ) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.ComponentPackage.Init () [0x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.ComponentPackage..ctor (System.String file) [0
>       x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.Packaging.Creation.PackageCreator.ValidatePackage (Syste
>       m.String packagePath) [0x00000] in :0
>         at Xamarin.Components.CreateManuallyCommandHandler.Invoke (System.String[] arg
>       s) [0x00000] in :0
>       rake aborted!
>       Command failed with status (1): [       mono xamarin-component/xamarin-component
>       ....]
>       C:/asposecloudsdk/Rakefile:33:in `block in '
>       Tasks: TOP => default
>       (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Can you post the command with parameters you are running to create the package?